# How to designate public endpoints using custom annotation in spring rest controllers?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, annotations, interceptor

We are using OAuth2 for securing our REST endpoints. Nearly all of our endpoints require authentication. We have couple of public endpoints. We configure spring security using @EnableWebSecurity. All the public endpoints are explicitly listed in the configuration (see "publicpath_x" in the example below). Instead of explicitly adding each new public enpodint in the configuration, it would be much easier to have a custom annotation, e.g. @PublicAccess which will designate each public endpoint. Is it possible to configure that endpoints annotated with this annotation will be considered as public, i.e. no authentication will be required? We don't want to designate public endpoints in path (e.g. all public endpoints path will start/end with "/public").

Security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatchers("publicpath1", "publicpath2").permitAll() //...
    }
}
```

Example public REST controller with custom annotation:

```
@RestController    
public class PublicController1 {

    @PublicAccess //our custom annotation
    @RequestMapping(value = "publicpath1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void publicEndpoint1() { 
        //... 
    }
}
```

I was trying the following classes with no success.

```
javax.servlet.Filter 
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter
```

Comment: Are you looking for custom annotations only or would you use an existent library?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@PreAuthorize` Annotations as method security

[Detail see here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations)